# Set Deployment URL for Firebase Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

i am very new in Firebase World, so i have a doubt, when i run my Firebase locally with `firebase serve` i can access the http endpoints with simple `localhost:5000/...` when i use [Lirebase Lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase)
 with `firebase.functions().httpsCallable('my_api_url')` aways call deploy url, like `https://us-central1-<project-id>.cloudfunctions.net/<api-url>`, have some way to set this firebase url to localhost for debug/deployment?

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Functions doesn't give you a way to customize the URL after deployment.  Callable functions aren't typically meant to be exposed directly to people anyway - they are meant to be invoked from your app code, which builds the URL automatically.

If you want a customizable URL endpoint, you could instead create an [HTTP trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events), then use [Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting) to [connect URLs it serves to Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions).